# SwiftUI: how to convert an Int to a Binding<Int>?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swiftui, binding

I need to convert an Int (index) to a Binding in order for my UI to update reactively in SwiftUI, how can I do this?

```
enum CurrentTodayView: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
    case Recovery = "Recovery"
    case Exertion = "Exertion"
    case Sleep = "Sleep"
    case Energy = "Energy"
    
    static func index(of aStatus: CurrentTodayView) -> Binding<Int> {
        let elements = [CurrentTodayView.Recovery, CurrentTodayView.Exertion, CurrentTodayView.Sleep, CurrentTodayView.Energy]
   
        //This returns an Int but I need to return a Binding<Int>
        return elements.firstIndex(of: aStatus)!
     }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding - bindings can always be manually created through closures. If the value cannot be updated they can be created with [`Binding.constant`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/constant(_:)) as there is no need to perform an update action.

Comment: @GarySabo Can you show how you'd like to use it in your `View`? You can't store mutable state in an enum like that, so you'd most likely be looking for something like `@State` on a view or `@Published` on an `ObservableObject`, which will both be a `Binding` without doing anything extra.